# Using the Salient WordPress theme cuts the header logo cut in half

Tags: wordpress, css

Problem: Logo appearing cut in half, and menu items chopped off
- Theme: Salient 8.0.15

[image: Logo cut in half]

I have no custom CSS yet.

Comment: You're uploading the logo wrong or the template your using has an issue. Either way, as a paying customer you should contact the author ([ThemeNectar](https://themeforest.net/user/themenectar)) of [Salient](https://themeforest.net/item/salient-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4363266) at Theme Forest. You should also make sure that you update Salient to version 8.0.15 (April 15th, 2017). If you encounter any CSS/PHP/HTML problems on-going then the suitable Stack is Stack Overflow, not Pro Webmasters, as programming related issues are off-topic.

Comment: I suspect the <div> for the logo area has a fixed site. You can change that to height:auto by putting in some custom CSS after you identify the <div> with developer tools.